# Gmail add-on disappears

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, gsuite-addons

I have a Gmail add-on that usses the following in its appsscript.json file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "GMT",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Gmail",
      "serviceId": "gmail",
      "version": "v1"
    }]
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE",
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
  },
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://mail.google.com/", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic"],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "<REDACTED>",
    "logoUrl": "<REDACTED>",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "getContextualAddOn"
    }],
    "primaryColor": "#41f470",
    "secondaryColor": "#94f441"
  }
}
```

Is there a particular thing I need to do to keep the add on visible in Gmail? Sometimes it seems to disappear after a few hours and the only way to get it to appear again is to uninstall and install it again.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a bug, are you a G Suite user?

Comment: Nope I use it on my personal Gmail account.

Comment: I see, then I recommend you to report this through Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392207) if you have the steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

It does not related to your app json file. The reason that you are facing that is because your add-on seems to be having some troubles after running some time. There might be bugs in your add-on script.
Would you share your script so I can review it?